# Android responive design wont work

Tags: javascript, android, html, css

I am trying to get my website to have responsive design but when i import the css files into the
html it only shows a white screen, both in Windows version of Chrome and the Android version.
Also i am debugging via usb through Chrome,

here is the files:

**HTML**

```
<?php 
require_once ("Includes/simplecms-config.php"); 
require_once ("Includes/connectDB.php");
require_once ("Includes/session.php");
?>
<! DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="keywords" content="">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..//Styles/global-style.css"> 
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..//Styles/font-face.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" href="..//Styles/input.css">        
<script src="..//script/main_script.js"></script>
<title></title>
</head>
<body id="fullWrapper">
    <div id="logo">the point</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The mobile version is in a map called 'mobile', so the link would be

`localhost:8080/mobile/index.php`

and the css file is in

`localhost:8080/styles/global-style.css`

`localhost:8080/styles/font-face.css`

`localhost:8080/styles/input.css`

I have tried to change location on the css files so one css file would be in the
directory folder and one is in the mobile folder.

Comment: Please post the content of your css files. That way we are able to help you out much better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out chrome developer tools: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode.

It allows you to emulate a device right in your desktop browser. That way it is much easier to debug and fix issues.